# GIT - '~/repo.git/' is not a git command

Tags: git, smartgit

I have a problem with with remote git repo and local repo (using SmartGit).

I'm creating remote repo on my server via ssh:

```
> cd ~
> git init repo.git
> cd repo.git
> touch readme
> git add .
> git commit -m "Initial commit"
```

From here everything seems perfect. Now I'm trying to clone repo using Smartgit with command

```
ssh://user@server:22/~/repo.git
```

Everything is cloning well. I make changes in readme file, saving it and trying to commit and push and getting error:

```
The remote end hang up unexpectedly
git: '~/repo.git' is not a git command. See 'git --help'
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
GIT_TRACE=2 git push origin master
```

and see what is happening to debug the issue.

Update:

It is trying `git-receive-pack`

Try doing below:

```
git config --global remote.origin.receivepack "git receive-pack"
```

And then do the push again.

Other things you can try:

On the remote server setup a bare repo:

```
git init --bare
```

And then try cloning and pushing to it.

Comment: Where can I do this in SmartGit?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using the full path instead of the home shortcut (~), e.g.,  `git clone ssh://user@server/home/tuergeist/repo`

This works for me on linux and also on WindowsXP in a git bash.

You also should obmit the `.git` extension, this may confuse your tools, as it expects a bare repository. (But I'm not sure)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify port 22; that's the default port for SSH. Also, SSH is the default if you specify `user@server:path`.

Try cloning with just...

```
user@server:~/repo.git
```

instead.