# git push to local path is not working anymore

Tags: git

I was able to pull from origin where origin points to some local path in the local machine (/source/projectname/) when i try to push i get error saying

```
git: '/source/projectname/' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
```

and the repository exists.

/source/projectname/ is a bare repo. Similar setup works in windows. Any idea ?

chmod 777 also didn't help.

Comment: What command do you type? `git push`?

Comment: git push origin master.

Comment: What git remote -v return?

Comment: origin  /source/projectname/ (fetch)
origin  /source/projectname/ (push)

Comment: Do you have git aliased to anything? (do alias return something for git?)

Comment: @Vonc, No... We don't have...

Comment: What git are you using? On which OS? Cygwin?

Comment: Also, do you have a pre-push hook, as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/26426677/6309?

Comment: @VONC,git version 1.9.5
RHEL 6.6

Comment: no hooks at all. Even to brand new git bare repo im not able to push.

Comment: And `/source/projectname` is a valid path?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/8427803/6309: what `GIT_TRACE=2 git push origin master` returns?

Comment: @Vonc, yes, it is... git pull says it is up to date. I have problem only with git pull.

Comment: @vonc, trace: built-in: git 'push' 'origin' 'master'
trace: run_command: 'git-receive-pack '\''/tmp/mani/test/.git'\'''
trace: exec: '/bin/sh' '-c' 'git-receive-pack '\''/tmp/mani/test/.git'\''' 'git-receive-pack '\''/tmp/mani/test/.git'\'''
trace: exec: 'git-/tmp/mani/test/.git'
trace: run_command: 'git-/tmp/mani/test/.git'
git: '/tmp/mani/test/.git' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: @Vonc, tried this in  freshly created one.

Comment: Was the freshly create one a bare repo? because it should have been `/tmp/mani.git`, not `/tmp/mani/.git`. Meaning, a `cd /tmp; git init --bare mani` would create a `/tmp/mani.git` folder.

Comment: @Vonc, same with bare too. trace: built-in: git 'push' 'origin' 'master'
trace: run_command: 'git-receive-pack '\''/tmp/mani/bare'\'''
trace: exec: '/bin/sh' '-c' 'git-receive-pack '\''/tmp/mani/bare'\''' 'git-receive-pack '\''/tmp/mani/bare'\'''
trace: exec: 'git-/tmp/mani/bare'
trace: run_command: 'git-/tmp/mani/bare'
git: '/tmp/mani/bare' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: Did you made at least one commit before pushing?

Comment: @Vonc, obviously yes, wierd but true. Im able to push using git 1.7.1

Comment: Ok. 1.7.1 on the same RHEL 6.6? But not 1.9.5?

Comment: @Vonc, yes git 1.7.1 on the same box...

Comment: I seem to have the same problem.

Comment: @ClaytonC, i would recommend either 1.7.1 or latest git. I was able to push with both the version.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to install 1.9.1, and it works for me now. Is it very unusual to use a local repository? Why aren't more people encountering this problem?

Comment: @ClaytonC, i have seen people using local repository. Since this issue is associated with only one version people didn't notice.